# Can the function be triggered by anything but document or window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem with Javascipt...

I need to run a function, triggered by a mouseover, but it only seems to work with putting document or window at the start of it.

Here's the code

```
var cursor = document.getElementById('#two');

document.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {

    cursor.blur();

})
```

As you see, 'document' is put before adding event listener. I'm sure there's an easy way.

I would rather it be triggered by an HTML link.

Thanks for you time...

Comment: "putting document or window at the start of it" what does this mean?

Comment: Do you want the `cursor.blur()` to be triggered when a link is hovered?

Comment: Event listeners have to be associated with **something** in the DOM. You could attach the listener to `cursor` for example.

Comment: document.addEventListener...

(there is document at the start)

Comment: @Pointy that didnt work...or I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You'll have to provide a better explanation: what elements are involved? What does the HTML look like? It's pretty much impossible to understand your problem given what you posted.

Comment: Im trying to make a navigation menu, that you go :hover over a link and the size of it increases. Im using :focus to pause the new size of the link. But I want it to go to its original size, by hovering over another link. I cant seem to disable :focus, but I was thing the blur() might be a way, but I'm probably doing it wrong...

Answer (score 1):

So obviously you are trying to mouse over a div with ID 'two' and blur it, so you can add the event listener to the div like this:

```
let target = document.getElementById('two');

target.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
   target.blur();
})
```